# Blender 2.80: What is the difference between "Rendered" and "Look Dev" display modes?

Tags: 3d-view

By pressing "Z" inside the 3D viewport in Blender 2.80 one can access the display modes of Blender. I would like to know the differences between "Rendered" and "Look Dev". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

LookDev uses the eevee renderer and some pre-selectable hdris to light your object. It ignores the lights in your scene. Rendered uses the lights in the scene, and you can change between cycles render and eevee.